# Fedora nfs mount dissappears

Tags: linux, fedora, mount, nfs

I have a small host running Fedora 18 (3.6.11), with a nfs set to server a /mnt/dir.

The problem on the client running Fedora (3.11.6) after just a minute or so the mount disappears. SELinux is disabled on both host and client, and I am able to see the nfs mount on client and both read and write to it. But after a few minutes it dissapears.

-------/etc/fsttab entry-----

```
my-serv:/mnt/server /mnt/share/  nfs4 rw,noatime,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,intr,hard 0 0
```

After mount -a,

```
  $ ls -l /mnt/share/ 
    -rw-r--r--  1 root     root         0 Jun 22 05:50 test
    ......
```

a few moments later,

```
    $ ls -l /mnt/share/
    total 0
```

Comment: This question interests me, but both the question and the answer confuse me.  What was the real problem?  /mnt/share and /mnt/netshare are two different directories, for one.  Then, the answer is even more confusing, because ext3 and nfs are unrelated because one is an on-disk filesystem, and the other is a network filesystem.  I was going to do some clean-up edits to the question and answer, but being confused by the content makes them un-editable.

Comment: It must be painful on the inside to see such errors in a post, no?

Comment: the fstab entry mounts the remote directory at boot on the local system. I'm pretty sure you're still going to have it unmount, becuase that's part of the way autofs works...it dynamically automounts when you need the directory `ls -l /mnt/share`, and umounts after the timeout has elapsed. But, everytime you `ls -l` the directory, you'll see the contents.

Comment: Sure, I get that. The problem was that before I setup automount that mount actually did umount after 60* seconds (unknown short time period).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So appears, by using autofs I am able to resolve the nfs mount from disappearing. Removing the fstab entry and adding the following to /etc/auto.master and /etc/atuo.misc per Fedora docs.

---/etc/auto.master----

> /mnt /etc/auto.misc

----/etc/auto.misc----

```
share/       rw,noatime,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,intr my-serv:/mnt/dir
```

Comment: The nfs is disappearing because you have it set to auto-mount (and it still should the way you have it configured). Automount dynamically mounts the remote directory hierarchy onto the local filesystem mount point. It also automatically unmounts it, after a set amount of time has passed (I think the default is 5 minutes - the way you have it set now). You can change the timeout in the /etc/auto.master config file by adding a third column `--timeout 60` where the number is time in seconds. --timeout is the time the system waits before an automatic `umount /mnt/share/` will occur.

Comment: Ok, but the way I understand automount is that as soon as I request access say ls -l /mnt/share the system will mount it again? This appears to work as expected so far.

Comment: After verification of the timeout autofs does appear to work as expected. Which helped that there was a typo in my actual /etc/auto.master -------------------share/       nfs,rw,noatime,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,intr my-serv:/mnt/dir--------not--------------share/        nfs rw,noatime,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,intr my-serv:/mnt/dir

Comment: mount through /etc/fstab, continues to fail miserably

Comment: I'm pretty sure fstab mounts at boot (is that not working?). NFS auto mounts as the directory is needed and preforms umount when the directory hasn't been used for the --timeout specified (I think in the auto.misc file...). Make sure autofs is running (but stop it before you shut the system down - otherwise the boot process slows waaaay down).